# How to list stopwords filter in ElasticSearch when ES machine is not accessible

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words

I use the service through RestAPI and have no access to machine itself. However, I'm able to call IndexAPI and AnalizeAPI through Rest.
I need to list all stopwords of specific filter.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index settings easily using the command below. In the response, you'll see the analyzers and filters definitions.

```
GET /your-index/_settings
```

Comment: I know what are my filters. I need list stopwords of concrete stopword filter. If for example my filter is "stopwords_en.txt" I want to read content of the file through API like, "a the us you me of by an in on...."

Comment: Stopwords are not defined in ES, but in Lucene, the underlying library. Since stop words are pretty stable, you can find the list directly in the Lucene source code at https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.java